# why the below code is causing frag error?

Tags: c, network-programming

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
struct protoent *proto;

char **p_aliases;


if(argv[1]==NULL){
    char name[25];

    printf(" give a valide protocol name\n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    proto = getprotobyname(name);
}
else{
    proto = getprotobyname(argv[1]);
}
if(argv[1]==NULL){



    printf("%s the protocol name is :\n",proto->p_name);
    printf("%s the protocol alias  is\n",proto->p_aliases);
    printf("%d the protocol number is \n",proto->p_proto);

    return 0;
    }
}
```

// i'm not getting the proper output, just a fragmentation fault

Comment: Instead of using `if(argv[1]==NULL)` use `if(argc < 2)`.

Comment: Check you second if, it should be argv[1]!=NULL

Comment: @prince, I don't think that is a problem. he has already declared `name` array, which he uses to get `protoent` structure in `proto`, hence, `proto` may not be NULL.

Comment: "Fragmentation Fault". And now I'm laughing my arse off.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with this code:

1. `argvc < 2` would be more robust than `argv[1] == NULL`, though that's probably not the issue here.
2. There's nothing to prevent `scanf` reading more than the 25 characters you've allocated.
3. The second `if` will mean there is *no* output at all if `argv[1]` is non-null.
4. `getprotobyname` returns a null-pointer when the name is not recognised, but you don't check.
5. You try to print `proto->p_aliases`, but that has type `char **`, so you probably need to print `proto->p_aliases[0]` (and should probably check that is non-null).

Anyway, besides all that, when you get a seg fault it's better to run the code under an debugger before you go ask other people to do your work for you. The debugger will probably tell you exactly where the problem is, and if it doesn't you can step through the code and narrow it down very easily.

Comment: well thank you all for the answers. i figure it out, the problem is solved.

Comment: yes when i added [0] to the proto->p_aliases the code ran, so thank you for the help.